# locked Ubuntu screen - apps do not detect locked status

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 12.10 (happens also in 14.04) but I did not really like Unity GUI because of performance issues and total inability to easily customize launcher. So I switched to Xubuntu, which is much faster BUT I have a problem, that our company messaging software is not able to detect when I lock the screen so it does not change my status to away. It works in Unity, but does not in Xfce nor in Cinnamon which I am testing right now. Is there any settings or command to make OS properly announce that screen was locked?

Comment: this happend to me as well, I guess the problem is due to a bug in Xfce.

Comment: which messaging software are you using? and are you using all of xfce's default settings/programs or is it highly customized? are you using any compositors?

Comment: I am using IBM Lotus Sametime Connect. What is compositor? :-] And as I said it works with Unity.

Comment: Xfce uses different locker program, `xscreensaver` AFAIK, which is rather old and lightweight and doesn't use modern interprocess communication bus, like `dbus`. I think the problem is here: your app is not notified about the locked session. Does the app have any configuration option to switch the status after a period of idle time? Like other IM clients do.

Comment: well of course the app have this option. How else would I find out that it does not work? ;) But I don't think that xscreensaver is being used in cinnamon. The credentials dialog looks like default Ubuntu lock screen...

Answer (score 0):

xscreensaver doesn't support dbus as SkyRaT already pointed out.  The package list for xubuntu lists xscreensaver near the bottom: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xubuntu-desktop

Using a screensaver with dbus support should help.  If you're not particularly attached to Xubuntu, you could also test out ubuntu-gnome from a VM to see if it works with your app.  Ubuntu-gnome is an official Ubuntu flavor, and doesn't use unity or xscreensaver by default.  http://ubuntugnome.org/